On stackexchange.com, the inbox message count erroneously briefly shows 0 upon page reload
On the stackexchange.com homepage, the inbox message count erroneously shows 0 upon page reload. Example:

Tested with the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10.

OK, I reproduced it. This seems to only happen on the main https://stackexchange.com site. Not, for example, any child site like physics.stackexchange.com but just the base domain. On other pages (like this one) on load the counter already shows up. On OK, I reproduced it. This seems to only happen on the main https://stackexchange.com site. Not, for example, any child site like physics.stackexchange.com but just the base domain. On stackexchange.com it first has no counter showing, then pop-ups with a zero, then it shows the actual count.

@VLAZ is correct, and it's a really minor bug.
